# Find darkest color in image with python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I was just wondering you could find the darkest colour in a greyscale image with python. I would prefer using pillow but OpenCV would be fine.
I found [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2009-April/005634.html) but couldn't make sense of it.
If this is simple just say.

Thanks

** edit **

The issue that I have is that with the rest of the script the darkest colour is very unlikely to be black.

Answer (score 3):

So in the image, after you read using OpenCV or Pillow, and because it is grayscale, the darkest "color" should be 0, which is black. The range of pixel values is from 0 and 255. If you want to find the darkest value, you can just use the minimal function.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("2.png", 0)
print(min(img.flatten()))
```

"For grayscale images, the pixel value is a single number that represents the brightness of the pixel. The most common pixel format is the byte image, where this number is stored as an 8-bit integer giving a range of possible values from 0 to 255. Typically zero is taken to be black, and 255 is taken to be white."

Reference: https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/value.htm

Comment: The issue that I have is that with the rest of the script the darkest colour is very unlikely to be black.

Comment: updated. as long as the image is grayscale, you can use it.

Comment: when I do this I get the following `>>> import cv2
>>> img = cv2.imread("/Users/theoturner/Desktop/python image stuff/testimg.png", 0)
>>> print(min(img.flatten()))
1
>>>` I am doing something wrong? Because the output shouldn't be 1

Comment: @tejt Any color can be black as long as it has a value of 0. within each color Hue there ca be hi-value and low-value, 255 values. So values (gray scale) live with in each Hue.

Comment: @tejt, I don't think there's wrong, sometimes the darkest or lowest value could be other than 0, in your case, 1 is the minimal, so it is the darkest if I understand your comment right.